# grammar mistake in "so low that can be ignored"

Tags: sentence-structure, passive-voice

In my sentence:

> The impact of the proposed method for 5 jobs **is so low that can be** ignored.

the grammar of the highlighted part sounds odd and unusual. What's wrong?

Comment: '...that _it_ can be ignored', where _it_ refers to _the impact_.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "it".

The impact of the proposed method for 5 jobs is so low that **it** can be ignored.

You need a subject pronoun before the verb in this sentence, being "it".